# Faster way to create Boolean columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating new Boolean columns based on whether or not other columns contain certain string values.

This is what I have tried

```
def function(data):
        data["col1"] = 0
        data["col2"] = 0
        data["col3"] = 0
        for i in range(0,len(data)):
            if ("cond1" in data.loc[i,"old_col1"].lower()) or ("cond2" in data.loc[i,"old_col1"].lower()):
                data.loc[i,"col1"] = 1
            elif ("cond3 " in data.loc[i,"old_col1"].lower()) or ("cond4 " in data.loc[i,"old_col2"].lower()):
                data.loc[i,"col2"] = 1
            elif ("cond5 " in in data.loc[i,"old_col1"].lower()) or ("cond6 " in data.loc[i,"old_col3"].lower()):
                data.loc[i, "col3"] = 1

    function(data)
```

But it doesn't scale well to larger datasets.

Are there better ways to implement Boolean columns, col1-3, that would perform faster?

Comment: "which works" <- are you sure about that?  `"cond1" or "cond2" in ...` doesn't do what you may think it does.

Comment: Can you post the df.head()?

Comment: Sorry, it has been edited to reflect what I intended to write. Unfortunately, I cannot post the head due to the nature of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple str.contains on all data

I made an example data frame, as you did not provide one

```
  col1       col2        col3
0  foo   cucumber   HogsWatch
1  bar     selery   hogswatch
2  baz  Porcupine  Watch Hogs
```

You can use apply to get a function to work over a whole dataframe

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A', flags=re.IGNORECASE))

    col1   col2  col3
0  False  False  True
1   True  False  True
2   True  False  True
```

#### Merging it back

This means that you can produce a new data frame with the boolean columns and if you want, you can join it into the original dataframe

```
bool_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A', flags=re.IGNORECASE))
df = df.merge(bool_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['', '_bool'])

  col1       col2        col3 col1_bool col2_bool col3_bool
0  foo   cucumber   HogsWatch     False     False      True
1  bar     selery   hogswatch      True     False      True
2  baz  Porcupine  Watch Hogs      True     False      True
```

### Multiple conditions

Of course you can make more complicated regexes in `str.contains`, such as

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A|O', flags=re.IGNORECASE))

   col1   col2  col3
0  True  False  True
1  True  False  True
2  True   True  True
```

### Separate conditions

I notice that you have different conditions for each column, this is also achievable with this methodology, but it is a bit more complicated, still fast though.

First we create a data frame of all the actual matching strings

```
conditions = {"col1": ["ar", "f"], "col2": ["er", "c"], "col3": ["Hog", " "]}
for col_name, strings in conditions:
    regex = "(" + ")|(".join(strings) + ")"
    df_cond = df[col_name].str.extract(regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE).notnull()
    df[col_name + '_matches'] = df_cond.T.max().T
```

Produces

```
  col1       col2        col3 col1_matches col2_matches col3_matches
0  foo   cucumber   HogsWatch         True         True         True
1  bar     selery   hogswatch         True         True         True
2  baz  Porcupine  Watch Hogs         True        False         True
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified as

```
data['col1'] = data['old_col1'].apply(lower)=='cond1' | data['old_col1'].apply(lower)=='cond2'
```

or

```
data['col1'] = data['old_col1'].apply(lower).isin(['cond1','cond2'])
```

Comment: `.apply` is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
data["col1"] = 0
data["col2"] = 0
data["col3"] = 0
data.loc[data["old_col1"].str.lower().isin(["cond1",  "cond2"]), 'col1'] = 1
data.loc[data["old_col2"].str.lower().isin(["cond3",  "cond4"]), 'col2'] = 1
data.loc[data["old_col3"].str.lower().isin(["cond5",  "cond6"]), 'col3'] = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the `if`/`elif` structure of the OP's code.  For example if the condition is met for 'col1', then the conditions won't be checked or assigned for 'col2'/'col3', even if they are met.  In the OP's code, the row level sum of 'col1'/'col2'/'col3' is 1 at maximum, where this solution allows for the sum to be up to 3.

Comment: yes, you are right, but adding another condition would help, reading line by line in a lot of data is not fast at all.